# Power BI :: How to create a forecast in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, forecasting, forecast

**GOAL: **I want to create a forecast of the month based on the last 3 months.

I found [this documentation](https://blog.enterprisedna.co/create-dynamic-forward-forecasts-in-power-bi-w-dax/) which looks easy.

Unfortunately when I try to put it in place on my side even the very first calculated measure is not working:

```
CostsBack1M = CALCULATE(SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), DATEADD('Usage details'[date].[Date], -1, MONTH))
```

Note how I used `SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency])` because I needed to port that column form another table.

I hope using `SELECTEDVALUE` is the right way to do it. There was no other option, the autocomplete was not working.

Also the `date` is coming form another table.

I want to put all the Measures to a dedicated table:

[image]

I don't know what is wrong here.

the calculation from the documentation looks quite straight forward but when I put it into a card or a line chart everything is blank.

And there are no errors. Why?

Comment: Passing the result of `SELECTEDVALUE` to `CALCULATE` does not look like the correct approach. Small sample dataset together with expected result would be useful.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to put the calculated measure inside the same table where the data comes from?

Comment: No. A measure can reside in any table. But what is your intention in creating `SELECTEDVALUE('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency])`? There is no aggregation here.

Comment: @JosWoolley , if I remove SELECTEDVALUE this is what happens: https://snipboard.io/LRFvdM.jpg

Comment: Yes, but `SELECTEDVALUE` is not in itself an *aggregating* function, such as `SUM`, `AVERAGE`, etc., so I'm at a loss as to what it is you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you @JosWoolley. If I don't put `SELECTEDVALUE` nothing work. So I put `SELECTEDVALUE` and nothing work. If I try to use `SUM` I only have a dot in the middle of a line dashboard. If I put `AVERAGE`... average is not what I want. 
So what should I use?

Comment: Actually I tried to substitute `SELECTEDVALUE` with `SUM` and on a card I can see the results but they always show the current month. Not the previous month.

Comment: The issue may be with your dates. You say "*the date is coming form another table*", yet in your formula you are passing dates from the *Usage details* table to `DATEADD`. What relationship is there between the *Usage details* table and this other table? Has this other table been marked as a date table?

Comment: @JosWoolley , not sure what happened, maybe it was the cereal this morning, but now `SUM` is working. Post your answer and I will label it as the right one

Comment: Good to know! Have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace `SELECTEDVALUE` with `SUM`.