# Basic forecasting: multiply AVG [ThisMonth] total * number of days till the end of the month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, forecasting

> What I have now:

I already asked help about how to [calculate a forecast in Dax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75801682/power-bi-how-to-create-a-forecast-in-dax) and the result was this:

```
CostsForecast = 
VAR Minus1MonthCosts = CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), DATEADD('Usage details'[date], -1, MONTH))
VAR Minus2MonthCosts = CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), DATEADD('Usage details'[date], -2, MONTH))
VAR Minus3MonthCosts = CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), DATEADD('Usage details'[date], -3, MONTH))
RETURN
DIVIDE(Minus1MonthCosts + Minus2MonthCosts + Minus3MonthCosts, 3, 0)
```

Basically it divides the last 3 months of data

> What I want to have ideally:

I don't want to base my forecast to the past months.

What I would like to have is to take the average of all days from the beginning of the month and multiply it by the number of days that remains till the end of the month.

**EXAMPLE:** Let's say that today it's the 23 of March:

[image]

So the result should be something like:

```
Forecast = 
CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]) + 
    (AVG('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]) * REMAININGDAYS)
```

Because if we have spent $23,000 in 23 days, that means $1,000 per day and multiply that * 8 = we are probably going to spend $31,000 at the end of the month.

I think this should be easy, I just don't know to catch the number of days form now till the end of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always hard to give exact DAX in these cases as it very much depends on your model, relationships and how you plan to use the measure. However, given the single table with the following data:

[image]

286/23 = 12.43 multiplied by 8 remaining days = 99.48

```
Measure = 
VAR m = EOMONTH(MAX('Usage details'[Date]), 0) 
VAR d = DATEDIFF(TODAY(), m, DAY)
RETURN 
DIVIDE(
    CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), MONTH('Usage details'[Date]) = MONTH(TODAY())),
    DAY(MAX('Usage details'[Date]))
) * d
```

[image]

**Updated single measure.**

```
Measure = 
VAR m = EOMONTH(MAX('Usage details'[Date]), 0) 
VAR d = DATEDIFF(TODAY(), m, DAY)
VAR c = CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]), MONTH('Usage details'[Date]) = MONTH(TODAY()))
VAR a = DIVIDE(c, DAY(MAX('Usage details'[Date]))) * d
RETURN 
a+c
```

Comment: Hi and thank you @David Bacci, the query works, I can dee that `99.48`. But to that  `99.48` I also need to add the  `286` which are the 23 previous days. Because the forecast needs is the sum of what we have already paid + what we think we are going to pay.

Comment: And strangely enough when I try to do that with a new measure that sum your measure plus the previous 23 days `Measure 2 = CALCULATE(SUM('Usage details'[costInBillingCurrency]) + 'Measure Table'[Measure])` the result is just too close to the first 23 days. Seems like the forecast is not added, just a few dollars are added.

Comment: I'll update so it is in a single measure for you.

Comment: You can have my girlfriend, @David Bacci

Comment: Lol :D :D :D :D

Comment: Wow. Powerbi has many benefits compared to powerquery that I had not previously considered

Comment: Haha - this has made my morning. :D